# assembly x86 JMP to relative address more than 127 (7F)

Tags: assembly, x86, processor, opcode

I'm not very fluent in assembly; and what I'm trying to achieve is the following:

```
00001 INC EAX
00002 MOV EBX, 22
00003 JMP 140 <-- Here I want to jump +140 from the current EIP
...
00143 RETN <-- I want to land here
```

I learned about short, far, near jumps in assembly x86, and I can't seem to figure out how do I do the jump I want, the nearest solution was a short jump:

```
EB8F JMP xx <-- It would work if I'm jumping into a place less than 7F, but my jump is bigger than 127 (7F).
```

`EB8F` is the opcode for my instruction.

How do I jump for 140 bytes *forward* from the current EIP?

Comment: Not sure what syntax you are using, but how about JMP NEAR 140? That should translate to E9xxxx ([JMP rel16](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/JMP.html)) which is a relative near JMP allowing for -32768 to +32767,

Comment: Are you using debug.exe (or debug.com) to enter this? Ancient versions of debug don't support the `near` modifier. The `debug.exe` that came with Windows XP do support it. I'd suggest a real assembler.

Comment: many of us learned x86 assembly using debug, it was a very very useful tool, today?  who knows, but then absolutely.  it was my IDE basically.

Comment: assembly language is defined by the assembler, the program that reads it and turns it into machine code.  unfortunately for instructions sets like x86 where they have a zillion encodings for jmp, mov, etc, lead to assembler differences above and beyond the AT&T vs Intel mess.  So you have to look at your specific tools to see what they want.  You might be able to hand edit the binary or write a program to modify/write the binary then disassemble with the tool, if debug.exe then load the .com file and disasemble and hope the diassembly syntax is the same as the assembly syntax (not always true)

Comment: @MichaelPetch I think your answer is the closet to what I want, but I can't find any documentation about it :( can you elaborate more and maybe give a working example?

Comment: The usual syntax in most assemblers for jumping 140 bytes from the current position is **JMP $+140**, which assembles to **E98900** in 16bit mode or to **E987000000** in 32bit mode.
You could also label the statement which you want to land at, and jump to that label.

Comment: Michael *linked* to the documentation! What you want is a NEAR jump, as opposed to a SHORT jump. Your assembler should support the NEAR and SHORT keywords, but you shouldn't need them. `JMP $+140` should work and cause the assembler to emit the correct code. If you tell us which assembler you're using, we can tell you the proper syntax.

Comment: another way if you have some spare bytes is jumping to some address within 127 bytes then put another jump at that address to the exact position

Comment: @old_timer today you can use OllyDbg on Win32 and EDB on Linux as a similar but much more powerful "IDE". Not sure if they can save the assembled code though.